# TimerTask inside of onDraw() Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-view, android-bitmap

I have an Android application that I am working on with Android Studio. I have a custom view that gets rendered from another activity. Inside of the custom view's onDraw() function, I schedule a new timer task to redraw a part of the UI. Initially, when I did this I was getting a SIGSEGV error, but I was able to fix that by adding this: **setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)**

However, after adding this, the Bitmap I drew inside of the Timer doesn't appear on the Canvas.

**Here is some of the code for better understanding:**

```
List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>(); 

public CustomView() {
   super(context);
   patch = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.person);
   patch = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(patch, 60, 60, true);
}

protected void onDraw() {
   if (drawPatch) {     // draw patch is a static boolean var that gets set to true 
                        // from the activity using this view

      timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            if (currentTime == timeBetweenSpawns) {
               people.add(new Person(x, y)); // x, y represents the location of the
                                             // person on the canvas
               currentTime = 0;
            } else {
               currentTime++;
            }
         }

         for (Person person : people) {
             person.movePerson(); // moves the person on the canvas
         }

         for (Person person : people) {
             canvas.drawBitmap(person.getBitmap(), person.getX(), person.getY(), null);
         }
      }, 0, 1000);
   } 
}
```

**What I am trying to do:**

CustomView represents a map for a game. I want to draw people moving on the map in the game and repetitively redraw the people to make it seem like they are moving smoothly. The issue is, I don't want to redraw the entire CustomView when I do this since the only thing changing in the CustomView is the location of the people (also for context there is a lot of other stuff being drawn in the onDraw() function in CustomView, I just omitted it for brevity). The timer logic I attempted above was an attempt to do this, but it didn't work.

**Is there a better way to only redraw the Person objects in the people list without having to invalidate and redraw the entire view?**

**Extra Context**

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        for (Grass grassLocation : grassLocations) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(grassLocation.getBitMap(),
                    grassLocation.getX(),
                    grassLocation.getY(),
                    null);
        }

        for (Path pathLocation : pathLocations) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(pathLocation.getBitMap(),
                    pathLocation.getX(),
                    pathLocation.getY(),
                    null);
        }

        canvas.drawBitmap(monumentLocation.getBitMap(),
                monumentLocation.getX(),
                monumentLocation.getY(),
                null);

        for (Indicator indicatorLocation : indicatorLocations) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(indicatorLocation.getBitMap(),
                    indicatorLocation.getX(),
                    indicatorLocation.getY(),
                    null);
        }

        for (Turret turretLocation : turretLocations) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(turretLocation.getBitMap(),
                    turretLocation.getX(),
                    turretLocation.getY(),
                    null);
        }

        if (combatStarted) {
            if (currentTime == timeBetweenSpawns) {
                addPerson(); // add a new person
                currentTime = 0;
            } else {
                currentTime++;
            }

            // Move all enemies, check if person has reached monument
            for (Person person : people) {
             person.movePerson(); // moves the person on the canvas
            }

            for (Person person : people) {
             canvas.drawBitmap(person.getBitmap(), person.getX(), 
             person.getY(), null);
            }

            invalidate();
        }
}
```

Comment: AFAIK you can't do that since once you drew on a canvas it "sticks". Your best bet would be to either draw again only that part of the canvas with nothing on it and then redraw the people's location. I do think though that re-drawing the whole thing should be easier and better and if you have a lot of logic there maybe try to re-think your architecture as usually you'd want your onDraw to mainly draw with as little functionality as possible due to it being called a lot of times

Comment: Thank you for the response. Could you clarify on what you mean by "draw again only that part of the canvas with nothing on it". Also, would there be performance issues from repetitively calling invalidate() assuming its called every 10ms when the people objects are moving? Also, do you think the Animation class could be applied for the people movement or would animating each people object along the screen be the same as repetitively calling invalidate() (in terms of efficiency)?

Comment: Well, to be honest I'm not quite familiar with all the drawing logic, how ever, calling invalidate is definitely not recommended for every 10ms call. What I mean by drawing again is, say you want to move a point from 5,5 to 30,5 so you redraw the canvas with no point at 5,5 (with appropriate color, radius, shape, everything) and then re-draw your point on 30,5. Usually, one way I know such stuff are being implemented is that you have a game engine which contains all ui object and in it's onDraw you are iterating every object and calling it's onDraw passing the same canvas as parameter

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense. Do you have any ideas for how I could redraw only the people without redrawing the rest of the canvas? I was trying to make a separate view that specifically displayed the people only, but I couldn't figure out how to overlay that custom view onto the original view that contains the map. I feel like if I only had to redraw the people every 10ms the performance wouldn't be too bad. For more context, I will provide my entire onDraw() function in my original post.

Comment: I'm not familiar with your game logic but I assume grass, path, turrents and things like this are static, if that's the case it would be much better to have a bitmap data member that if it's value is null, you do all this drawing logic once, otherwise you simply redraw that bitmap on the canvas without re-calculating all the places and locations of the objects. if you do that as the first line of your onDraw it will erase everything, making drawing the indicators and everything else dynamic the only thing to do. it's also possible to apply same logic, meaning you draw them all on a seperate

Comment: bitmap and after you have prepared that bitmap with all your objects you draw that bitmap after you drew the background bitmap, that'll results only 2 "drawing" calls on the main canvas, I believe that will be much more efficient.

Comment: to redraw only a part of view , use `view.invalidate(Rect) ` or `view.invalidate(left, top,right,bottom)`